# How to capture return value of git merge?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that interacts with a git repository.
But this script results in an error:  `line 8: [: -ne: unary operator expected`

Apparently because the variable `returnValue` evaluates to an empty string rather than an exit code. I would like to get the exit code of `git merge` to an variable.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

repo="$HOME/experiment"
cd $repo

returnValue=$(git merge --ff-only --quiet)
echo -e "merges return value is ${returnValue}"
if [ $returnValueMerge -ne 0 ]; then
  echo -e "There was a problem while doing git merge"
  echo
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Don't even bother.  Just do `if ! git merge ...; then echo "redundant error message that is line noise because git just gave a perfectly good error message" >&2; exit 1; fi`

Comment: Better yet, just do `git merge ... || exit`

Comment: In my scenario I expect the local repo to be clean and a fastforward-merge to be successfull. I wanted to do mitigating actions, if that was not the case and inform my future self about these assumptions. Maybe I should have had given more context in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response code of the last command executed (in this case `git merge`)
Is stored on the variable `$?`

You should thus save this specific variable as soon as the command is executed to use it afterwards

You should rewrite your code as is

```sh
git merge --ff-only --quiet
returnValue=$?
echo -e "merges return value is ${returnValue}"
if [ $returnValueMerge -ne 0 ]; then
```

Comment: This is *not* best practice.  Best practice is `if ! git merge ...; then ... fi;`

Comment: This is not what the OP want, he want to play with return codes, perhaps later do something different for each one,

Comment: Yes, thank you. Though now I learned that aparently git merge only throws 0 or 1. I was hoping for more error codes, in order to tell the user how to fix it. The user beeing future me.